# Show that the following group action has a non-zero singleton orbit.

Tags: finite-groups, group-actions

Let F be a finite field of characteristics prime p.Let G be a group of order $p^r$ for some r.Let G acting on $F^n$ for n>1.Then show that there exist a non-zero vector in $F^n$ whose orbit will be singleton.

Comment: Here are som hints. First, $|F^n|$ is a power of $p$. Second, $F^n$ is the disjoint union of $G$-orbits. Third, if $0 \in F^n$ is the zero-vector, then $G0 = \{0\},$ so we have one orbit of size $1$. Fourth, pick any $v \in F^n$ and consider the stabilizer $S_v = \{g \in G | gv = v \} \subseteq G.$ Then $S_v$ is a subgoup of $G$ and $|Gv| = |G:S_v|$. Are you familiar with that? Fifth, what do we know about the possible sizes of $S_v$ given the size of $G$?

Comment: yes ...order of $S_v$ can be some pth power..so??.

Comment: This implies that $|Gv| =|G:S_v|$ is a power of $p$. Now, suppose that $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ are the orbits of $G$ on $F^n$ where $U_1 = \{0\}.$ Then, as I said above, $|F^n| = |U_1| + \cdots+|U_m|.$ Now we know that every number in this equation is a power of $p$, possibly $1 = p^0$. We also know that $|U_1|= 1.$ So, is this the only $1$ in that equation? Or must we have more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the follwing nice theorem:

**Th.:** Let $\;G\;$ be a finite $\;p$- group acting on a finite set $\;X\;$ , and put

$$X^g:=\{x\in X\;;\;x^g=x\;\forall\;g\in G\}$$

Then,

$$|X^G|=|X|\pmod p$$

**Proof:** We know

$$X=\bigsqcup\,\mathcal Orb(x)$$

Now,

$$|\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G:G_x]\;,\;\;G_x:=\{g\in G\;;\;x^g=x\}$$

and thus all the orbits are of size a power if $\;p\;$(including $\;p^0=1$) , and

$$x\in X^g\iff |\mathcal Orb(x)|=1$$

so that in fact

$$|X|=\sum_{x\in X^G}1+(\text{powers of}\;p)=|X^G|\pmod p$$

Your problem is now solved by noting that zero is *always* a fixed point in $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ , and thus there *must* be at least another fixed point since $\;|\Bbb F^n|=p^m\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb N\;$